# Python PyQt5: QListWidget doesn't accept drops

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, qt5, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I have tried to create a simple QListWidget that accepts text dropped into it. Can't make it to work. The drop-event doesn't even get triggered, the drag event is on the other hand.
Can anybody point me in the right direction? What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton,  QLineEdit, QLabel, QListWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 drag and drop'
        self.left = 500
        self.top = 400
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 250
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        editBox = QLineEdit('Drag this', self)
        editBox.setDragEnabled(True)
        editBox.move(10, 10)
        editBox.resize(100,32)

        listwidget = CustomLabel(self)
        listwidget.move(130,15)

        self.show()


class CustomLabel(QListWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        if e.mimeData().hasFormat('text/plain'):
            print("dragged")
            e.accept()
        else:
            e.ignore()


    def dropEvent(self, e):
        print("dropped")

        self.addItem(event.mimeData().text())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You need to initiate the drag somehow.  Take a look at the [drag and drop docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html).

Comment: Dont get it...sorry

Comment: That only tells that particular widget to *accept* drops -- it has nothing to do with actually starting the drag operation.  Please read the docs linked to in my first comment.

Comment: Reading the doc wasn't enlighten for me, I must say. Can't fully understand the code there, since I am only familiar with python so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a `QListWidget` doesn't handle dropped text, so you have to reimplement the mime-data handling, like this:

```
class CustomLabel(QListWidget):    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def mimeTypes(self):
        mimetypes = super().mimeTypes()
        mimetypes.append('text/plain')
        return mimetypes

    def dropMimeData(self, index, data, action):
        if data.hasText():
            self.addItem(data.text())
            return True
        else:
            return super().dropMimeData(index, data, action)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if your code is based on [this example](https://pythonspot.com/pyqt5-drag-and-drop/).

The main difference is that your `CustomLabel` inherits from `QListWidget` rather than `QLabel`.  Unfortunately `QListWidget` inherits from `QAbstractScrollArea` and it's the viewport widget associated with that scroll area that will receive the various drag/drop events -- not the `QListWidget` itself.

Your best bet might be to install an event filter on the viewport....

```
class CustomLabel(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        # Install the event filter.
        self.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        if e.mimeData().hasFormat('text/plain'):
            print("dragged")
            e.accept()
        else:
            e.ignore()

    def eventFilter (self, obj, event):
        if obj == self.viewport():
            print("event")
            if event.type() == QEvent.DragMove:
                print("moved")
                event.accept()

                # Your drag enter event processing code goes here
                return True
            if event.type() == QEvent.Drop:
                print("dropped")
                event.accept()

                # Your drop event processing code goes here
                return True
        return super(CustomLabel, self).eventFilter(obj, event)
```

**Edit 1:**

You will probably also need to add...

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent
```

Comment: You are right, its a slightly altered version of that example. I forgot the rename the class from CustomLabel to something else..but the App wont start/ no window shown when I replace the CustomLabel class with your code.

Comment: See **Edit 1**.

Answer (score 1):

Amazing. Now that works.
Thanks a lot for you help.
So thats the whole code put together:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget,  QLineEdit, QListWidget


class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 drag and drop'
        self.left = 500
        self.top = 400
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 250
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        editBox = QLineEdit('Drag this', self)
        editBox.setDragEnabled(True)
        editBox.move(10, 10)
        editBox.resize(100,32)

        listwidget = CustomList(self)
        listwidget.move(130,15)

        self.show()


class CustomList(QListWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def mimeTypes(self):
        mimetypes = super().mimeTypes()
        mimetypes.append('text/plain')
        return mimetypes

    def dropMimeData(self, index, data, action):
        if data.hasText():
            self.addItem(data.text())
            return True
        else:
            return super().dropMimeData(index, data, action)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```